# Limits of joint distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

Hopefully a simple question to clear up some understanding.

[image]

Goal: calculate $f_Y(y)$

My thoughts: to calculate $f_Y(y)$ we need to integrate with respect to $dx$ so in my mind from calculus this is like considering (infinitesimally) thin vertical slices of width $dx$ where each slice has area of $dA = (x+1) - x\: dx$. In other words constant height 1 and integrating over all such $dx$.

If we imagine starting at $x=0$ and sliding the thin vertical slice from left to right we can see the left and right bounds of $x$ now have two equations for them indicating we need to split $f_Y(y)$ up.

My question is whether this is a valid way to think of setting up the question by relating to calculus with areas and slicing or whether I should be setting things up differently. The reason I am asking is that when I first did this question I set it up with $x$ limits from 0 to 1, which is incorrect.

Solution [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-ii/lecture-9/MIT6_041SCF13_assn05_sol.pdf) in case needed (Q5).

Answer (score 1):

So we can model $f(x,y)$ as 
\begin{equation}
 f(x,y) = K  \qquad \text{if } (x,y) \in A
\end{equation}
and $0$ elsewhere. So, let's find $K$,
\begin{equation}
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) \ dxdy = \int_{A} f(x,y) \ dxdy = 1
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
K
 \int\limits_0^1
 \int\limits_{x}^{x+1}
   \ dydx = 1
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
 K = 1
\end{equation}
An alternative is that the area of the trapezoid is $A = \int_{A} \ dy dx = 1$. Now, let's find $f(y)$ by marginalizing out $x$,i.e. 
\begin{equation}
 f(y) = \int f(x,y) \ dx
\end{equation} 
Notice that $y$ is defined between $0$ and $2$ so we must cover all this range to define $y$. If $0 < y < 1$, $x$ will vary from  $x = 0$ till  the lower side of the trapezoid defined by $x = y$, so we should get
\begin{equation}
 f(y) = \int_0^y \ dx = y, \qquad \text{ if } 0 < y <1
\end{equation}
On the other hand, if $1 < y < 2$, then $x$ will vary from the upper side of the trapezoid defined by $y = x+ 1$ (or $x = y-1$) till $x = 1$, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
 f(y) = \int_{y-1}^1 \ dx = 2-y, \qquad \text{ if } 1 < y <2
\end{equation}

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think you mean when $0<y<1$ that $x$ will vary from 0 to $y$. Also, I get this (this is just the answer from the solutions) - I'm not really after a repetition of this but whether thinking of $dx$ slices is a correct approach, if that makes sense.

Comment: you're right i have edited.

Comment: and how would you slice your $x$ ?

Comment: For $0<y<1$ why can't we do $\int_{0}^{y} 1-y \,dx$? i.e. base x height

Comment: You're integrating $f(x,y)$ which is $1$ inside the trapezoid and zero elsewhere. From where does $1-y$ come from ?

Comment: $1-y$ is the height of a $dx$ slice for $0<y<1$

Comment: nope, the height is $x = y$ (defined by the lower side of the trapezoid) Please see the figure that i have added to my answer

Comment: I'm confused. The infinitesimal area $dA$ for $0<y<1$ is given by a thin vertical slice of width $dx$ and with height bounded by $y=x$ on the bottom and $y=1$ on the top. Do you see my confusion? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: all what you said is correct except the boundaries: It is bounded by $0$ from the bottom and $y = x$ from the top

Comment: Is that not for a horizontal (i.e. $dy$) not vertical slice? The vertical slice has width $dx$.